# ¿Se pueden eliminar los permisos de escritura local persistente con javaScript?

Tags: javascript

estoy probando el almacenamiento persistente de la API FileSystem. He probado cómo la aplicación pide permisos al usuario, con una ventana tipo alert, pero sólo sale la primera vez, como es lógico, después de aceptar permisos. En un entorno de desarrollo, me gustaría probar varias veces este tema, es decir que cada vez que se inicia la aplicación, borrara primero los permisos, para que los vuelva a solicitar.¿Se puede hacer esto? Aquí está el código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Solicitar permisos al navegador.
    navigator.persistentStorage = window.persistentStorage || navigator.webkitPersistentStorage;
    window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

    navigator.persistentStorage.requestQuota(1024*1024*10, 
        function(grantedBytes){
            // Tras recibir permisos para almacenar archivos,
            // se solicita un punto al fileSystem
            window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler);
        }, function(e){console.log("Error: ", e);}
    );

    // Crear un archivo y escribir en el
    function onInitFs(fs){
        // Creamos el archivo en el fileSystem

    }

    function errorHandler(){

    }
</script>
```

Una solución intermedia, es que cada vez que pruebe la aplicación, aumente el tamaño de espacio solicitado, entonces al solicitar más espacio, vuelve a pedir permisos, pero es una solución muy tosca.

Comment: Parece ser que ya no se puede utilizar este sistema para almacenamiento persistente, sólo nos queda el localStorage, bastante limitado. Cierro el tema.

Comment: Este procedimiento que intentas, tienes que hacerlo si o si desde la ejecución de javascript en navegador? lo digo porque está muy limitado por los browsers, en cambio si lo hicieses desde nodejs probablemente tendrías más cancha. Si tu objetivo es sólo el almacenamiento persistente, hay otras opciones mejores, no sólo el localStorage sino también, desde que salió HTML5 se introdujo IndexedDB, una bbdd implementada en navegador con el paradigma muy parecido a noSQL

Comment: La mejor solución es utilizar IndexedDB, integrado en HTML5. Todo lo demás quedó obsoleto: cookies y la API FileSystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La mejor solución es utilizar IndexedDB, integrado en HTML5. Todo lo demás quedó obsoleto: cookies y la API FileSystem.

Con IndexedDB no se necesita pedir permisos puesto que es una API segura, con un paradigma completamente diferente a los cookies y la API File System. El uso de IndexedDB es un poco complicado de entender y habituarse al principio, puesto que su programación se basa en transacciones con la base de datos, y sus almacenes de objetos. Estas transacciones disparan unos eventos, pasando los valores recuperados.

A continuación adjunto unos enlaces que yo mismo utilizo para informarme con más detalle:

https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/IndexedDB-840092-dup/Conceptos_Basicos_Detras_De_IndexedDB

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/IndexedDB-840092-dup/Usando_IndexedDB

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-indexeddb--net-34673